# Bundle ID Is Not Available?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-developer-program, bundle-identifier, apple-id

So I have been getting this Bundle ID error saying it is not available and don't really know how to fix it. Here is the error:

There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
An App ID with Identifier 'com.team.AppName' is not available. Please enter a different string.

So right now in my app I  am 100% sure that my bundle Id matches the one I have entered in the developer system. I am not to sure why this error keeps on appearing and would appreciate any help someone has to offer.

PS:
I am not to sure if this is a problem but my developer team on Xcode (like the one I am using in my app) is different than my developer program apple id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the error shows when you submit to appstore ? Did you created an entry for your app in there ?

Comment: yea the error is when I am trying to submit my app to the app store. What do you mean by creating an entry. What I did was I went to the app ID tab and was follwoing the steps over there.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes because you don't have an app record in your iTunes connect account which matches the current bundle identifier. You should create an app record in your iTunes Connect account before uploading the app.

> Before you can upload an app for distribution on the App Store or Mac
>   App Store, you create a record in iTunes Connect. This record includes
>   all the information that appears on the store for the app, and all the
>   information needed to manage the app through the distribution process.

You can read more about it here : [Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1)

Comment: I think you are wrong because when you go to create an app on itunes connect it requires you to register the app id you created or the one I was trying to create where the errors were appearing.

Comment: @RohanVasishth: Did you created the app id in your developer portal ? If yes, then I'm correct (So go ahead and read the linked article), else the issue is you took a duplicate bundle id. (Bundle ids should be unique globally)

Comment: This "app record" is exactly what I'm having trouble with. I can't create an app record because it says I have no bundle id. When I go to try to add the bundle/app id, it says the bundle id is "not available". I read that this is because xCode8 does al the bundle id automatically. Well then what's the point if iTunes Connect cannot see the bundle id. Now I'm in a catch 22 where itunes connect won't see my bundle id but changing my bundle id will be a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: I am not to sure if this is a problem but my developer team on Xcode (like the one I am using in my app) is different than my developer program apple id

Of course it is a problem. In Apple's eyes, you're about to steal someone else's identifier.

What you could do is transfer the Id between accounts. Take a look at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html. It might take a while, though, and can only be performed by the Team Lead.

Comment: ok so I was able to fix this problem by simply changing my bundle ID to com.DeveloperAccountAppleID.AppName.